# Regex to username that contains alphanumeric characters and at most one underscore symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a username. I want to have a regex that,

1. At least 4 characters long.
2. Must contain only letters, numbers and an optional underscore
3. It must not end with an underscore
4. It must start with a letter

i have tried regex,

```
    /^(?!_*\_*\_*)[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9_]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$/
```

```js
function validate(username) {
    if ((/^(?!_*\_*\_*)[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9_]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$/).test(username)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(validate('hej_gd'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - At least 4 characters long.

At the beginning, match `(?=.{4})` to ensure there are at least 4 characters

> It must start with a letter

Start by matching a letter with `[a-z]`, then

> - Must contain only letters, numbers and an optional underscore
> - It must not end with an underscore

Match zero or more letters and numbers, followed by an optional `_`, followed by one or more letters and numbers, with `[a-z\d]*_?[a-z\d]+`:

```js
function validate(username) {
    return /^(?=.{4})[a-z][a-z\d]*_?[a-z\d]+$/i.test(username);
}

console.log(
  validate('hej_gd'),
  validate('hej_'),
  validate('_hej'),
  validate('h_j'),
  validate('h__j')
);
```

The `i` flag allows you to keep from having to repeat the `a-zA-Z`.

The underscore shouldn't go in a character set with the other characters because your requirements are that it may contain *an optional underscore* - you want to make sure there's no more than 1 underscore, so there should only be one place where it can possibly match (with `_?`).

Comment: It will allow to start with the digit, so it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Another version to address "It must start with a letter"

```
function validate(username){
    if (username === undefined || username === null)
        return false;

    return /^(?=.{4})[a-z]([_]?[a-z\d]+)*$/i.test(username);
}
```